# Adding function handlers in cell array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, cell-array

I have a bunch of anonymous functions stored in a cell array as follows:

```
F = {@(x) x + 1, @(x) x * x}
```

I want to create a new anonymous function to add them all up and average the result given an input `x`. `F` can have arbitrary number of function handles and is generated at run time. If `F` is known, then it is simply `f = @(x) (F{1}(x) + F{2}(x)) / length(F)`. But I don't know how to append all elements of `F` onto this new anonymous function (presumably in a loop?) How would I do this?

Comment: Have a look at [`cellfun`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`cellfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to define a function that evaluates each function `f` in `F` using just one line. An anonymous function handle for arbitrary `F` and `x` is as follows:

```
F = {@(x) x + 1, @(x) x * x};
%// Build anonymous function that evaluates each function, sums, 
%// divides by length of F
new_F = @(x,F)sum(cellfun(@(f)f(x), F)) / length(F);
```

Then, to evaluate, simply call:

```
x = 2; %// data to apply fcns on
result = new_F(x, F)
```

Comment: Wow! Did not know this is valid syntax! The functional programming is strong with Matlab.